# html audio muted on click play and again on click mute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want html audio code which will fit functions:
on click audio on
and on click audio again off.
I searched whole day and found only this code:

html

```
<a href="#noscroll" id="mute">toggle sound</a>
```

javascript

```
var audio = document.getElementById('background_audio');

document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

but this starts automaticly, I want audio start muted, then same function as it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can set audio to muted on load. `audio.muted = true;`

```
var audio = document.getElementById('background_audio');
audio.muted = true;
document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```